# Confidence Interval for Proportion: Is my use case appropriate

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, proportion

Suppose I have 1,000,000 customers and exactly 25% of them use my new app.

I would like to look at some customer segments and decide if there use of the app is significantly different from this proportion. I'd like to construct a 95% confidence interval.

```
+----------------+------------+
| All Customers  |  1000000   |
+----------------+------------+
| Use App        | 250000     |
| Proportion     | 0.25       |
| Standard Error | 1.875E-07  |
| 95% CI Lower   | 0.24999963 |
| 95% CI Upper   | 0.25000037 |
+----------------+------------+
```

The standard error was calculated as `(p*(1-p))/n = (0.25*(1-0.25))/1000000`

My questions:

1. Assumption for the sampling distribution of p to be normally distributed is that it is a random sample of less than 10% of the population. Here I have the whole population, don't I? What should I do here? On page 275 of [Open Intro Statistics](https://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php?stat_book=os) (Chapter 6, Inference for Categorical Data) there's a box that states:

> TIP: Reminder on checking independence of observations. If data come
>   from a simple random sample and consist of less than 10% of the
>   population, then the independence assumption is reasonable.
>   Alternatively, if the data come from a random process, we must
>   evaluate the independence condition more carefully.

2. If I would like to compare segments, e.g. customers with higher avg. spend or younger customers, would these segments be biased by there very nature and thus not comparable? i.e. If I found that their average proportion p was 26% and not 25% and thus outside the 95% confidence interval for all customers, can I say that these two example segments are significantly different or not?

Comment: Proportions are not normally distributed by definition: they are the mean of 0/1 variables. The true distribution of a proportion does not depend on sample size. You ought not ask people to go read texts elsewhere in order to answer your question, but should instead quote the relevant material in your question.

Comment: @Alexis Updated my text to read "sampling distribution of p" as opposed to the distribution of p. I'm asking that, if my "sample" proportion p is 0.25, then is the assumption above violated? Namely ```data come from a simple random sample and consist of less than 10% of the population```? Since my sample is in fact the population, the entire customer base, how can I proceed? Or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the effort to clean up. What are you hoping to get out of making a CI? Confidence intervals are a form of statistical that is used to communicate how reliably a *sample statistic* estimates a *population statistic* (or, if you prefer, *population parameter*). If you have data on the whole population there is no inference. If you have data on whole sub-populations there is no inference there either. When we have a sample proportion what we are communicating with the CI is—loosely—a plausible range of values for the population proportion. But you don't need a plausible range!

Comment: Hi @Alexis. "What are you hoping to get out of making a CI". And " If you have data on the whole population there is no inference". That's actually what I was seeking verification on. Because in this case I have the universe of persons, the population in the whole database of customers. The question I'm really trying to answer is this: Remember example context is % of customers who use our app. If overall our database use the app at a proportion 0.25, then if I segment our database to look at a particular group of people, e.g. Millennials, how much different from 0.25 would the ...

Comment: proportion for this segment be to be considered "different"? E.g. if Millenials use the app at a rate of 0.33 as opposed to 0.25 for the customer base as a whole. By attempting to create a CI around the population p of 0.25, my goal is to see if the the p for millenials, 0.33, is outwith this CI and thus "different". Do you understand my question? As you can see, I'm a little confused. Thanks for your help

Comment: Doug Fir "if I segment our database to look at a particular group of people" But you have the entire universe of these people also, so I do not think there is inference here either. If the subgroup's proportion is a different number, that's your evidence that it is a different number.